# no keyboard or mouse usable in win7 installation/settings screen with only usb3

Tags: windows-7, usb

Keyboard and mouse works in `bios`, but when `in win7 installation screen`, they are failed?
After google, mostly the problem is `win7` is lack of `the USB 3.0 drivers`, and they just tell us to use `USB2.0` port, or even use `PS/2` port.
Then how can we deal with only with `USB3.0` or their suggestions is not suitable for us?

**update 2**
stuck in firstly `settiing windows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ***[self mark]***

If you meet above problem, this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJyQViv2iJA) may help you and save time.
I have try to use `USB2.0`, but most of `BIOS` settings is not found in my computer. After lots of retry, I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJyQViv2iJA) that tell us how create `a Windows 7* installation image to include USB 3.0 drivers`.

this tools required:

- [Win7 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7)
- [windows-usb-dvd-download-tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) to install ISO into your USB
- [Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility) to install `USB 3.0 drivers`

If link is failed, try to search tools'name.

**update 2**
After above actions, my compute is stuck in `setting compute(set name)`.
==> I solves it by set `BIOS-USB_SETUP's USB Virtual KBC Support` `Enabled`, the refer link is miss.

Finally Done...